# How can I share a list between 2 Linux device drivers

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have 2 drivers, One of them is an In-tree module and the other one is a second-stage module.
I am trying to share a linked list defined in a common module being used by both of the drivers.

Ex: 4 Files:

**common_file.h** => Contains the "static LIST_HEAD(my_list)" declaration.

**common_file.c** => Here I am appending the list using list_add().

**Module1.c** => includes common_file.h

**Module2.c** => includes common_file.h

Observation:

The list shows as non-empty if accessed from the common_file.c

The list is Empty if accessed from either Module1 or Module2.

**Q1 - Is there a way to make the list accessible from the modules?**

**Q2 - Please explain the behavior observed above.**

**Edit 1:-**
The static keyword is required as the header is included in other drivers also , so if I try to use `LIST_HEAD(my_list)` instead of `static LIST_HEAD(my_list)` I get the below linker error

`ld.lld: error: duplicate symbol: my_list`

Comment: I'm not an expert on kernel modules, but declaring a `static` variable in a header file seems odd. Would this not mean that any source file that includes it gets its own (static) version of it? I would expect to see `extern` variable declarations in a header file, and the actual definition in a .c file.

Comment: `static` means that it only exists in that file. And remember that #include means copy-paste. So you have `static LIST_HEAD(list);` in module1 and another `static LIST_HEAD(list);` in module2 and because they are static they're different.

Comment: Your "Edit 1" shows that you probably need to start with understanding the C programming in general. In the above comments it's explained that what you are doing is wrong.

Comment: Assuming the "common module" is a separate kernel module (a .ko file), you can define the list as a global variable in common_file.c (making sure it has a unique name such as `myfoo_list`), declare it as `extern struct list_head myfoo_list;` in common_file.h, and add `EXPORT_SYMBOL(myfoo_list);` to common_file.c to make the symbol visible to the other two kernel modules.